# Find all the entire functions $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|f(z)|\le|z|e^x,\,z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I am working on the following problem:

Find all the entire functions $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|f(z)|\le|z|e^x,\,z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $e^x=|e^z|$, so your relation is equivalent to  $|f(z)|\leq |z||e^z|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, Using the hint I got $f(z)=cze^z$ for $c\le 1$ is the required answer. Am I right?

Comment: Those are indeed all such functions, but $c$ should be in $\mathbb C$ with $|c|\leq 1$.